# A regex to replace a brand in HTML

Tags: regex

I am looking to replace a brand name in HTML but I want to avoid breaking brand mentions that might be part of a CSS class. I decided to try to allow only matches preceded by a space or a comma, but could be followed by anything except a dash, an underscore or a dot. But because a trailing dot could be a legitimate match, I want to allow it if t's followed by a space.

So far my regex looks like this:

```
([ ,])(brandname|brand name)(?![-_])
```

but I am stuck with how to negative match the trailing . but allow trailing .\s

```
Editing to give a few examples:

true:   brand name. something
false:  brandname.something
true:   ,brand name. something
false:  .brandname
true:   brandname something
true:   brandname,something
false:  brand name-something
```

Comment: What does this mean `the trailing . but allow trailing .\s` ?

Comment: I really think you would have better chances of getting this answered if you provided an example of a string that you want to modify along with an example of what it should look like after the bran replacing

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - Why link this as a dup to that html post ?

Comment: @KamilJanowski sorry, I have added them in the original post.

Comment: @Maxt8r Because you DO NOT parse HTML with Regex.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - Here I CAN  parse HTML with REGEX _In 2 Languages_  PHP https://regex101.com/r/p0t1H8/1 Python - https://regex101.com/r/BF0zIp/1

Comment: @Maxt8r ok Karen.

Comment: @maxt8r yes I agree. I can do what I want. I don't need someone telling me what I am allowed to do. There is no DOM in apps script so there is no option to parse it. Thanks for your solution. It was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I doubt you know what ok Karen means or who Dane Cook is, but in your circle of lezbots I'm sure you have thrilling days in your life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying

`[ ,]brand[ ]?name(?:(?![-_.])|(?=\.[ ]))`

```
 [ ,]                # space or comma
 brand [ ]? name     # brand name 
 (?:                 # Check ahead assertion
    (?! [-_.] )      # Not dash, underscore or dot
  | (?= \. [ ] )     # Or, dot is ok if followed by space
 )
```